# Matplotlib: How to change the location of names?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that reads a CSV file and outputs it to graphs. His window looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the names of the graphs Filter and step2 are on the left and all the others are on the right. This does not suit me. Here is my function

```py
def Grahp2():
    df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv',) 
    names = ['P', 'Filter', 'Answers', 'step','step2','Comulative', 'Delta_ema','ComulativePOC', 'Delta_P', 'Sum','SpeedUp', 'M' ]
    features = df[names]
    features.index = df['Time']
    axs = features.plot(subplots=True)
    cursor = MultiCursor(axs[1].get_figure().canvas, axs)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.19, hspace=0.05, top=0.99, right=0.988, bottom=0.052, left=0.055)
    plt.show()
```

Is it possible just in my method to make sure that all the names are in one particular place?

Comment: You could try first by keeping all the needed timeseries data as `arrays`, and keep all the names stored as `legend = ['col1','col2',...]` and so on. Finally. you can determine the location of the legend by following this syntax: `plt.legend(legend, loc ="lower right")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Grahp2():
    df = pd.read_csv('Датасет с дельтами ема.csv',) 
    names = ['P', 'Filter', 'Answers', 'step','step2','Comulative', 'Delta_ema','ComulativePOC', 'Delta_P', 'Sum','SpeedUp', 'M' ]
    features = df[names]
    features.index = df['Время']
    axs = features.plot(subplots=True)
    axs[0].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[1].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[2].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[3].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[4].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[5].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[6].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[7].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[8].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[9].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[10].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    axs[11].legend(loc = 'upper right')
    cursor = MultiCursor(axs[1].get_figure().canvas, axs)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.19, hspace=0.05, top=1, right=1, bottom=0.045, left=0.033)
    plt.show()
```